# How to append counter to an appended object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, cookies, counter

Is there a way to append a counter to short down a code. So, my code is

```
  $$("checkbox0").setValue(cookie.checkbox0);
  $$("checkbox1").setValue(cookie.checkbox1);
```

and so on... What I want to to is for loop

```
 for(i = 0; i <= columns; i ++) {
     $$("checkbox"+i).setValue(cookie.checkbox[i]);
  }
```

but it doesn not work for the last checkbox object. Does someone knows the hack for this? Thanks :)

Comment: Is that 'checkbox' an array? why checkbox[i]?

Comment: just replace to `$$("checkbox"+i).setValue(cookie["checkbox"+i]);` if checkbox is not array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable), although if at all possible it'd be best to use an array instead.

Comment: Solved thanks to Juhana javascript master, Thanks!